# Scrollbar does not appear and work in Jquery Mobile 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing **chrome extension** and using jquery mobile for it.

I have listview and many rows in it, i can scroll and see on my Mac(OS X) There is no problem.

When i install extension to another computer which is ***Windows or Ubuntu*** , scroll bar does not show and i can't scroll the rows.

Comment: Are you referring to the default extension panel? Or some sort of pop up or external panel

Comment: And did you specify a size for the window?

Comment: default extension panel and yes i did specify size for it

Comment: Okay if the scroll bar doesn't appear automatically it might  be one of the side effects of it being frameless have you tried manually creating a scroll function?

Comment: no i have not.How can i do that and should i do that ?

Comment: Essentially you just make a div for the side scroll bar and then use the jquery click and drag listeners to tell it to move the body or whatever else needs to be scrolled. There's a jquery plug in at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html if you're interested in that if you're not then I could probably help write some code to do this if you want the help

Comment: @Binvention i will try and let you know.Thanks !